# Group Input in configuration components (component configuration syntax)

Tags: angular

I have a very complex component that has a lot of **@Input()**s.
For the sake of readability I would like to group the input like *DexExtreme*'s grids do.

DevExtreme grids have a lot of Inputs and they have divided them like this:

```
<dx-data-grid
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    [remoteOperations]="false">

    <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10"></dxo-paging>

</dx-data-grid>
```

As you can see the paging arguments are not passed directly to `dx-data-grid` but throught
a child component `dxo-paging`.
I think this is a very good approach when you have very configurable components.

Anyone knows how to achieve the same result?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really about grouping Inputs but combining components. The key feature which is being used here is called [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) in Angular. It allowes you to fill predefined slots in the parent component with other components, which are passed from the outside.

The example you provided would have following structure. We would have two components: the parent `DxDataGridComponent` and the child `DxoPagingComponent`. You can define the inputs on both of them as you wish. Then the parent component needs to have a `<ng-content>` slot, where the child component will be projected to.

Additionally you can grab a reference to this child component in your parent component by using `@ContentChild`.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'dxo-paging',
    template: `
      <!-- Paging stuff -->
    `
})
export class DxoPagingComponent {
    @Input() pageSize;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'dx-data-grid',
    template: `
    <!-- DataGrid stuff -->
    <table>
    </table>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class DxDataGridComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @Input() dataSource;
    @Input() remoteOperations;
    @ContentChild(DxoPagingComponent)
    pagingComp: DxoPagingComponent;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
      console.log('Content initialized', this.pagingComp.pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz. I know what content projection is but I thought that `dxo-paging` didn't have a template.. I thought it was just a "container of paramenters".
I thought that becouse you can configure the Grid also via typescript without using dxo-paging component. You can do something like: this.grid.paging.pageSize = 3 and avoid using the elmenet <dxo-paging>

Comment: I also noted that using the Chrome Inspector there is no `dxo-paging` tag in the html

Comment: Hm ok - so generally you could remove the ```<ng-content>``` slot from template and still access the ```DxoPagingComponent``` as I showed in the updated answer. In this way it would not show up in the template but you could access it's inputs and achieve so the desired grouping of inputs.